# Domain name in the address bar when using IP address. Where does it come from?

Tags: http, dns

When I use an IP address to access a website and after the site is loaded, the address bar display the domain name (instead of its IP). I was wondering where does this name come from? Is my browser doing a DNS query for the IP I provided? Or is it the site itself that is giving the browser its domain name (in the http header)?

(This happens in all the browsers I have tested (including Firefox).)

Answer (score 0):

Probably website script is redirecting from ip adress to domain name it self.